# Setup sandbox environment in Toloka

Tags: pool, crowdsourcing, toloka

This question is related to sandbox environment.

How to test the pool in Toloka before we release it?

Answer (score 1):

Create users, add them accesses.
To do that in section Users add trusted users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register in Sandbox: https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/sandbox.html. The main version of Toloka and its Sandbox are separate entities and have different websites. You need to have an account on both of them. When you register in the main Toloka you don’t automatically get an account in Sandbox.